# does h2o.glm model object not save 'weight_column' parameter?

Tags: r, h2o

I am using the h2o.glm module (in R). I tried to find the 'weights_column' specification value in the outputting h2o GLM model object but I can not find it. I looked into model@allparameters and model@parameters, none of these two objects contain the weights column information. Is the weight information saved anywhere in the model object?

Answer (score 2):

If you specify `weights_column` to GLM or any of the H2O algos, it will store the column name (not the actual column data) in the model object.  In R, it stores it in both `model@parameters` and `model@allparameters`.  Here's an example:

```
library(h2o)

model <- h2o.glm(x = 1:3, y = 5, 
                 training_frame = as.h2o(iris),
                 weights_column = names(iris)[4], 
                 family = "multinomial")
```

You can see the relevant info here:

```
> model@parameters$weights_column
$`__meta`
$`__meta`$schema_version
[1] 3

$`__meta`$schema_name
[1] "ColSpecifierV3"

$`__meta`$schema_type
[1] "VecSpecifier"


$column_name
[1] "Petal.Width"

$is_member_of_frames
NULL
```